# Select object from a drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a Razor view where I am editing a `Document` object and am trying to modify the associated `Currency` record.  The available `Currency` are listed in a drop down list.

I have two classes in EF, shown below.

```
public class Document
{
    public Currency CurrencyCode { get; set; }
}

public class Currency
{
    [Key]
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "Money")]
    public decimal ExchangeRate { get; set; }
}
```

I am creating the drop down list like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CurrencyCode.CurrencyCode, new SelectList(ViewBag.Currencies, "CurrencyCode", "CurrencyCode"), Model.LocalCurrencyCode.CurrencyCode)
```

When I post the view using a submit button I can see that the value is posted: `CurrencyCode.CurrencyCode:USD`.  The Model binder does a good job of binding all of my simple data fields (other fields not shown). But the Document.CurrencyCode object is left as null.

My plan was to only bring back the CurrencyCode value and then look up the actual object reference using Entity Framework and associate it. But right now I'm not even getting a half filled object back...

Comment: only values that are in a for helper (except display) will be returned back to the controller.  If you want document.currencycode to come back you should be it in a hidden for or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you passed a complex type model to your view. To get the selected value from `DropdownList`, you need to explicitly tell the model binder what model you want to bind data to. See below example:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CurrencyCode.CurrencyCode", new SelectList(ViewBag.Currencies, "CurrencyCode", "CurrencyCode"), Model.LocalCurrencyCode.CurrencyCode)
```

Comment: Perfect, my issue is resolved. I thought I was going to have to wrap it with a view model, but that did the trick.